# Returning all dates in dd/mm/yy format from the past 6 months

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to return all days from the past 6 months.

Per example:

```
Column1
-------
01-OCT-18
30-SEP-18
29-SEP-18
........
01-APR-18
```

@TimBiegeleisen - Your solution pointed me in the right direction, so you get the points.

@MT0 - "ADD_MONTHS" as far as I know is not used in T-SQL so the the clarification I believe was necessary. but thank you for the pointer with the updates will refrain from doing that in the future.

Comment: Are you looking to get rows from a table with a date column >= six months ago, or are you wanting to generate a list of dates from six months ago to now (or to the start of the current month)? Also, why do you need dd/mm/yy format? Years have four digits, so you should be using yyyy unless you have very good reason not to (e.g. for reporting purposes only; if anything is to be consumed by another program, four digit years should always be used).

Comment: You want to generate a list of all days in the past months, regardless of any table data, correct? Why do you want this solved with PL/SQL? Wouldn't a SQL query suffice?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: I am new to pl/sql came from t-sql and still learning the differences between the syntax so thought important to clarify, the idea is to produce a list of days from the past 6 months and a count of how many times a particular value has been recorded against each date e.g. 1st of the month has x amount of values , 2nd of the month has x amount of values etc.
not used to oracle dates in comparison to SQLSVR and a couple of the functions being different. This is a learning task so didn't want to post the whole question as I wouldn't learn anything.

Comment: @jackd102 First, that is not PL/SQL, it is just SQL (in the Oracle dialect). Second, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52758405/edit) with details of your table, some example data and your expected results. Please do not put updates into comments as they are not readable.

Comment: @MT0 Now it sounds like a calendar table join to another table, followed by an aggregation.  I'm out 20 points in any case.

Comment: @jackd102: Just in case you haven't understood yet: PL/SQL is a programming language available in the Oracle DBMS. Unlike other programming languages like C, Pascal, whatever, PL/SQL is deeply integrated in the DBMS and you use it to write triggers and functions etc. Some PL/SQL functions can even be called from Oracle's SQL queries. You, however, just wanted a SQL query ...

Comment: ... SQL is a standardized database query language, but the standard compliance and additional features differ from one DBMS to the other. Microsoft has named the SQL dialect in SQL Server T-SQL. Oracle has not invented a special name for their SQL dialect. They just call it SQL. You can call it Oracle SQL, if you want to make clear of which SQL dialect you are talking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compare each date in `Column1` against `SYSDATE`, 6 months earlier, and then display the dates in the format you want using `TO_CHAR` with an appropriate format mask:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(Column1, 'dd/mm/yy') AS output
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    Column1 >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6);
```

### Demo

Answer (score 3):

This will get you all the dates (in the format in your example) from the last 6 months:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/080b1/5)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE - LEVEL + 1, 'DD-MON-RR' ) AS Column1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY SYSDATE - LEVEL + 1 >= ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -6 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/080b1/5/0)**:

```
|   COLUMN1 |
|-----------|
| 11-OCT-18 |
| 10-OCT-18 |
| 09-OCT-18 |
...
| 13-APR-18 |
| 12-APR-18 |
| 11-APR-18 |
```

---

**Update**

> the idea is to produce a list of days from the past 6 months and a count of how many times a particular value has been recorded against each date

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/080b1/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

Create an example table with multiple rows for various days:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
          SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 0 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
UNION ALL SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
UNION ALL SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
UNION ALL SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 3 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
UNION ALL SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 4 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( c.Column1, 'DD-MON-RR' ) AS Column1,
       COUNT( t.value ) AS num_values_per_day
FROM   (
         SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - LEVEL + 1 AS Column1
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - LEVEL + 1 >= ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -6 )
       ) c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       ON ( c.column1 = t.value )
GROUP BY c.Column1
ORDER BY c.Column1 DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/080b1/5/0)**:

```
|   COLUMN1 | NUM_VALUES_PER_DAY |
|-----------|--------------------|
| 11-OCT-18 |                  5 |
| 10-OCT-18 |                  3 |
| 09-OCT-18 |                  7 |
| 08-OCT-18 |                  2 |
| 07-OCT-18 |                  1 |
| 06-OCT-18 |                  0 |
| 05-OCT-18 |                  0 |
...
| 14-APR-18 |                  0 |
| 13-APR-18 |                  0 |
| 12-APR-18 |                  0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

So for the additional task provided in your comment you might want to adjust Tim Biegeleisens solution a little bit:

```
SELECT TRUNC(Column1) AS "Day"
     , count(*) as "Count"
  FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY TRUNC(Column1)
 WHERE Column1 >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add more to it however this was the starting point I needed, I was over complicating the query by trying to use "CONNECT BY LEVEL" the query I had before worked fine for dates in the future but would not return anything previous to the sysdate (I will play around a bit more with the above to figure out how it works but for the time being I know enough).

Thanks for the answer, I was able to figure out the solution for what I wanted via the following:

```
SELECT  col1
FROM    table1
WHERE   col1 >= add_months(sysdate,-6)
```